# Fetching signature image for logged in user using docusign rest api

Tags: docusignapi

I have a project in which I have created a form containing fileds:-

1.) Name
2.) Signature

In signature column there is button "Add Signature" when click on button it opens popup to enter docusign email and password. Once click on login it get's signature image url of the user. But the problem with my code is I am not getting image.

My issue is I want to display signature image after authentication in my project. Please suggest me what is wrong in my code.

My project url is:-

http://surgimedik.esoftech.in/out/out.AddDocument.phpfolderid=1&showtree=1#popup1

admin / admin

You can check below url where I am getting image url. when you hit it it asks for login itstead of showing image.

http://surgimedik.esoftech.in/docusign/test.phpemail=akash@esoftech.org&pwd=Terminate@12345

```html
<?php

$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$password = $_REQUEST["pwd"];

$integratorKey = '4a394221-7742-4f39-8a90-9021732676e8';
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?include_account_id=true";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 200) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$userId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["userId"];
curl_close($curl);

$url_sig = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/$accountId/users/$userId/signatures";
$curl_sig = curl_init($url_sig);
curl_setopt($curl_sig, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_sig, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_sig, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$json_response1 = curl_exec($curl_sig);
$status_sig = curl_getinfo($curl_sig, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status_sig != 200) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status_sig;
    exit(-1);
}

$response1 = json_decode($json_response1, true);
$signatureId = $response1["userSignatures"][0]["signatureId"];

$url_sig1 = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/$accountId/users/$userId/signatures/$signatureId";
$curl_sig1 = curl_init($url_sig1);
curl_setopt($curl_sig1, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_sig1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_sig1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$json_response11 = curl_exec($curl_sig1);
$status_sig1 = curl_getinfo($curl_sig1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status_sig1 != 200) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status_sig1;
    exit(-1);
}

$result = json_decode($json_response11);
echo "https://appdemo.docusign.com" . $result->signatureImageUri;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong api.

Use the [getImageUserSignatures](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/UserSignatures/getImage/) api

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureId}/signature_image
```